# WebAPI post JSON string and map it to model

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

I must create webhook endpoint that will consume JSON messages.
Messages is send as x-www-form-urlencoded in form:

> key = json
>   value = {"user_Id": "728409840", "call_id": "1114330","answered_time": "2015-04-16 15:37:47"}

as shown in PostMan:

[image]

request looks like this:

> json=%7B%22user_Id%22%3A+%22728409840%22%2C+%22call_id%22%3A+%221114330%22%2C%22answered_time%22%3A+%222015-04-16+15%3A37%3A47%22%7D

To get values from request as my class (model) I must create temporary object containing single string property:

```
public class Tmp
{
    public string json { get; set; }
}
```

and method inside my controller that consumes that request:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("save_data")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveData(Tmp tmp)
{
    JObject json2 = JObject.Parse(tmp.json);
    var details = json2.ToObject<CallDetails>();
    Debug.WriteLine(details);
    //data processing
    return Content(HttpStatusCode.OK, "OK", new TextMediaTypeFormatter(), "text/plain");
}
```

As You can see Tmp class is useless.

Is there a way to get request data as this class:

```
public class CallDetails
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CallId { get; set; }
    public string AnsweredTime { get; set; }
}
```

I'm aware of `IModelBinder` class, but before I start I'd like to know if there is an easier way.

I can't change web-request format, by format I mean that is will always be POST containing single key - `JSON` yhat has json string as value.

Comment: why can't you change the content type to application/json when it is json that you are passing around?

Comment: Unrelated to the question, but I am bothered by the fact that you're using the `async` keyword just to do `Task.Delay(1)`

Comment: @MatiasCicero I've removed code responsible for processing data and saving it to database, I'm doing everything async so instead of changing method declaration I simply added `Task.Delay(1)` sorry if it is confusing.

Comment: @CallumLinington I've edited my question. By format I mean that it always will be POST request with single key-value pair. key is `JSON` and value contains json string

Comment: @Misiu So your question is _how to get rid of Tmp class_?

Comment: @tmg Yes, I want to do POST request as shown on screen (please notice different names inside request and my model) and have request data as `CallDetails` instance

Answer (score 4):

You can use `JsonProperty` attribute for mapping json object properties to c# object properties:

```
public class CallDetails
{
    [JsonProperty("user_id")]
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("call_id")]
    public string CallId { get; set; }
    [JsonProperty("answered_time")]
    public string AnsweredTime { get; set; }
}
```

Then it can be used without temp class:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[Route("save_data")]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveData(CallDetails callDetails)
```

---

**Update.** Because the data is sent as x-www-form-urlencoded - I think the way you handled it is most straightforward and not so bad. If you want to check another options here're some of them:

Option 1 - custom model binder. Something like this:

```
public class CustomModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var body = actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
        body = body.Replace("json=", "");
        var json = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(body);

        bindingContext.Model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<CallDetails>(json);

        return true;
    }
}
```

And usage: `SaveData([ModelBinder(typeof(CustomModelBinder))]CallDetails callDetails)`. Downside - you'll lose validation and maybe other stuff defined in web api pipeline.

Option 2 - `DelegatingHandler`

```
public class NormalizeHandler : DelegatingHandler
{
    public NormalizeHandler(HttpConfiguration httpConfiguration)
    {
        InnerHandler = new HttpControllerDispatcher(httpConfiguration);
    }

    protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        var source = await request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        source = source.Replace("json=", "");
        source = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(source);

        request.Content = new StringContent(source, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");

        return await base.SendAsync(request, cancellationToken);
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpPost]
public IHttpActionResult SaveData(CallDetails callDetails)
```

Downside - you'll need to define custom route for it:

```
config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "save_data",
            routeTemplate: "save_data",
            defaults: new { controller = "YourController", action = "SaveData" },
            constraints: null,
            handler: new NormalizeHandler(config)
        );
```

Comment: Thank You for reply, but what about request format? Data is send using POST with key=`JSON` and value=`{"user_Id": "728409840", "call_id": "1114330","answered_time": "2015-04-16 15:37:47"}`. I want to map that string to `CallDetails`

Comment: Thank You for update, as You wrote my initial option isn't bad. What I really want is to be able to use `ModelState.IsValid` inside methods. `DelegatingHandler` looks like the best option - I'll get my model right away, probably `ModelState.IsValid` will work (not sure on that). The downside is custom route. Maybe handler can be specified inside attribute? Do You know if this is possible?

Comment: @Misiu, I know that it is **not** possible to specify handler with attribute routing. And validation will work

Comment: In which cases validation should work? Only with DelegatinHandler or with ModelBinder or initial solution (JObject.ToObject<>)? Sorry for all the questions but I'd like to implement best solution possible.

Comment: Only with DelegatinHandler, in two other cases you'll need to run it manually (which is not so bad).

Comment: Sorry for such late reply. In my project I'm using FluentValidation. My only option is to create validator class and call `validate` on my model? Or can I make it working with `ModelState`?

Comment: If you'll go with DelegatinHandler, `ModelState` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Json.NET by NewtonSoft can help you [deserialize an object](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/deserializeobject.htm).  If your json property names don't match your actual class names you can write a custom converter to help.

**EDIT**

You could try this if you are on MVC6.  Change your parameter from type `Tmp` to type `CallDetails` and mark it with attribute `[FromBody]`, like this:

```
public IHttpActionResult SaveData([FromBody]CallDetails details)
```

For example look at the section "Different model binding" in [this post](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/1149/convert-aspnet-webapi2-aspnet5-mvc6).  However, I'm still thinking that you will need to deserialize manually because the property names of class `CallDetails` don't exactly match the incoming JSON properties.

Comment: I've added some more details to my question. Basically I want to remove usage of `Tmp` class and instead mapping request to Tmp and then to CallDetails I want to map my request to CallDeails from start.

Comment: Could You please post some code, and this would help a lot. Isn't there more generic solution? I have four methods that have similar problem. I'd like to have more reusable solution.

Comment: MVC5 also has `FromBody` attribute, but it didn't helped. WHen deserializing from XML we can use attributes for element names. Can similar thing be done with JSON?

Comment: Try to make sure that the posting form is including the `contentType: "application/json"` header and change your CallDetails properties to match the names in json.  You may be stuck with the Tmp class since your page is posting json wrapped in a key/value pair.

Comment: As I wrote in my question I can't modify request, because it is done by external service, all I'm able to set is URL to which request is done.

Answer (score 0):

You don´t forget to decode the url encoded before use JObject.Parse ?, it´s maybe works. And the properties of the object don´t match the json atributes

Comment: I've added some more details to my question. Basically I want to remove usage of `Tmp` class and instead mapping request to Tmp and then to CallDetails I want to map my request to CallDeails from start.